# jquery code for getting the href of 'a' tag near the button that is being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Good day.

I just want to get the href of a link once the button near the link is being clicked by the end user. But the problem is there are lots of buttons and links. So, if the end user will click the first button, it should display the "www.a.com". If the 3rd button is being clicked, it should display "www.c.com". Can any one help on how to get it done perfectly? Thanks...

```
<div>
<a href='www.a.com'>a</a><input type='button' class='btn' onClick='validate()' value='V'/>
</div>
<div>
<a href='www.b.com'>b</a><input type='button' class='btn' onClick='validate()' value='V'/>
</div>
<div>
<a href='www.c.com'>c</a><input type='button' class='btn' onClick='validate()' value='V'/>
</div>
<div>
<a href='www.d.com'>d</a><input type='button' class='btn' onClick='validate()' value='V'/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
alert($('div a').closest('a').attr('href'));
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `parent` and `child` like

```
function validate()
{
    alert($(this).parent('div').child('a').attr('href'));
}
```

Or even you can get it with `prev` like

```
alert($(this).prev('a').attr('href'));
```

Comment: What if the 'a' tag's link is a return value of its onmouseover event? How could my code get the said link?

Comment: When i tried your second option, it returned a NULL value.

Answer (score 1):

I should do it linke this:

```
$(document).on("click",".btn",function(){
  alert($(this).prev('a').attr('href'));
});
```

With this code the onclick is not needed

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
function validate()
{
   alert($(this).siblings('a').attr('href'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn").click(function () {
            alert($(this).parent().children("a").attr("href"));
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

remove onClick='validate()' from all  buttons
and try following code

```
  $('.btn').click(function () {

        alert($(this).prev().attr("href"));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use need `prev()` with source of event, also pass the source object to function

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XCT8W/1/)**

Html

```
onClick='validate(this)'
```

Javascript

```
function validate(obj)
{
   alert($(obj).prev('a').attr('href'));
}
```